# Can I use MSVCRT functions in my DLL Delay-Load Handler function?

Tags: dll, msvcrt

I have already added delay loading to my project, using the instructions in 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx

In the "delayhlp.cpp" (a sample implementation of the DLL load helper) `__HrLoadAllImportsForDll`, I saw that the writer avoids using any Standard C Library (MSVCRT) functions. Do I need to do the same in my handler function, which will be called by the sample DLL load helper?

I think the writer's reason is that someone might try to delay-load MSVCRT itself. I'm not going to do this. Will it then be safe for me to use MSVCRT functions?

**Background Info.** The reason for delay-loading the 3rd party DLL is because there is a function signature change between two versions, and I need to run my program using either version. I then provide a simple wrapper function to adapt the DLL's function signature to the one needed. This function is registered by the Delay-Load Handler (`__pfnDliFailureHook2`), when `GetProcAddress` fails.

**Some testing.** I added a breakpoint at the beginning of my handler function. I found that when the breakpoint is hit, the `msvcrt.dll` and `msvcr90d.dll` etc are already loaded (from Visual Studio's Modules pane). Does it mean that I can call CRT functions safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        // Check to see if it is the DLL we want to load.
        // Intentionally case sensitive to avoid complication of using the CRT
        // for those that don't use the CRT...the user can replace this with
        // a variant of a case insenstive comparison routine.
        //
```

That's the more relevant comment, **for those that don't use the CRT**.  You won't have a problem, the CRT is always loaded by the startup code.

Comment: Thanks! yes I found that CRT is indeed always loaded very early. (The ability to do case insensntive string compare will make it less error-prone to specify the alternative DLL path on the command-line.)